# what is a good approach in dealing with remote captcha validation in jquery?

Tags: php, validation

I am using Kohana's Captcha library which generates the captcha image. I am using jquery to validate the captcha. The problem is when I enter a wrong text in to match the image against, the captcha library seems to be generating another captcha image but won't output it in my current form. The validation is remotely done by calling a controller function to validate the captcha.

I can't seem to get get it done with this captcha library. Care to share your approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the ReCaptcha service. See examples/docs here http://recaptcha.net/plugins/php/

Comment: hi, the link is broken...can you provide another ?

Comment: Here you go. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php Seems they changed their site.

Answer (score 0):

What about using recatcha? A very powerfull easy to implement plugin?